# maven release from svn trunk file adds irrelevant projects to the release folder

Tags: maven, svn, release

I want to make a release from a project located in svn trunk named like `com.a.b` and I want to see my release under my tags folder. It is happening but maven release adds all the folders under the trunk with irrelevant ones to my release folder. I just want to add projects to release folder named like `com.a.b.c` or `com.a.b.d` .

edit: related parts of the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.1</version>
         <configuration>
               <tagBase>svn://local/base/tags</tagBase>
               <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
         </configuration>
</plugin>

<scm>
     <connection>scm:svn:svn://username:password@local/base/trunk/project</connection>
     <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://username:password@local/base/trunk/project</developerConnection>
     <url>scm:svn:svn://username:password@local/base/trunk/project</url>
</scm>
```

Comment: Than the tag already existed before. I assume the tags has been created once before and you missed to delete the tag.

Comment: which tag should I delete before run the release command, in pom.xml?

Comment: Of the release you are creating. Are you following the default layout in maven `projectName/trunk`, `projectName/tags`, `projectName/branches` ?

Comment: Yes I have the default maven layout. At the beginning there was no tag and nothing with same name.  I still don't understand what I made wrong. I tired to delete everything under tags folder and after that created a new release with a new name but same situation I had again.

Comment: Please show the pom configuration in particular the scm are of your pom file.

Comment: I edited my question adding pom.xml